# Changing state (visibility) of nested td

Tags: html, css

I would like to change the visibility of the td with `class="tempCLS"`. The structure is shown in the image below with html code.

In the css file I have tried doing `.tempCls {visibility : hidden; }`

I have also tried doing: `.tbl > thead > tr > .tempCls {... }`

[image]

Thanks for any help

Comment: Your code should work ([example](https://jsfiddle.net/evLb5qjc/)), is the stylesheet containing these rules definitely being loaded in successfully? (check the dev tools for network errors)  If so, is the style being overwritten by another style rule? (Check the dev tools style inspector)

Comment: Also, please include the HTML structure as text rather than images.

Comment: The html is created dynamically with JS.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
.tempCls {display:none; }
```

Comment: Doing .tempCls { what ever } Does not work because it's nested (I think).

Comment: I solved it by adding   `!important;`  I have no idea why it worked like this, but it worked

Comment: Maybe you have a CSS file that has already defined those style proprieties, adding `!important` overridden those proprieties.

Answer (score 1):

You need to know the difference between `display:none` and `visibility:hidden`

- **`visibility:hidden`** hides the element, but it still takes up space in the layout. e.g. `

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
.tmpCls{
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<h2>HTML Table</h2>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td class="tmpCls">Maria Anders</td>
    <td class="tmpCls">Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td class="tmpCls">Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tmpCls">Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

`

- **`display:none`** removes the element completely from the document. It does not take up any space but the code exist in source code and can be shown any time by removing the property.

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
.tmpCls{
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<h2>HTML Table</h2>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td class="tmpCls">Maria Anders</td>
    <td class="tmpCls">Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td class="tmpCls">Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tmpCls">Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

As for your concern about `<td>` being nested element, it does not matter or should not effect the css of element via class. Unless you have styled the element somewhere else. The hierarchy of importance of style is as follows

external css(external file with .css extension) => internal css(css style in `<style>` inside the same file) => inline css(css in `style` attribute within html tag) => `!important`

Comment: I do know the difference between the two. My problem was just that I could not apply css to that td class. I could just as well had used height, width or something else as an example. But thanks anyway

Comment: then as suggested in comments to the question share your css and html snippet. Stack overflow offers html,css and javascript code snippet posting in questions. That way tracking the issue will be easier

Comment: also in the Developer tools>Elements>Style try applying your style and see the difference

Comment: @user1960836 if my explanation helped you solve the issue, you should accept the answer so it can help others